# Compare dates from up to three datepicker fields, then populate another field with earliest one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web form written in Perl, HTML, CSS, and a smattering of Javascript.  I have a few jquery based Javascripts included, but am pretty new to Javascript and jquery, overall.

The form has three date fields which are populated with jquery's "datepicker" script.  Sometimes only one of the three dates will be entered, sometimes, two, and sometimes all three.

How could I compare the dates that are picked--whether it's one, two, or three, to identify the earliest date, and then take that date and populate another field on the form?

The form is an application for housing in an apartment building, and each apartment can have between 1 and 3 residents.  Each resident has to indicate the date on which they intend to move in.  Then my program needs to determine which of the dates is the earliest, and populate another field (the overall "earliest occupancy date") with that value.

I'd like to be able to have the "earliest occupancy date" filled instantly as the dates are entered (as opposed to having to submit the form, and then reload it to see the date get filled in).

Comment: If you want to fill in the field instantly without submitting the form to the backend, you can't use Perl. (I'm tempted to remove the perl tag from your question.)

Comment: I would recommend using angularjs for instant field update, will give an example soon

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot This is all front-end stuff and really has nothing to do with Perl.

Comment: Apologies if I should not have included the "Perl" tag.  There is a lot of Perl being used in the app (it's way beyond just a form--there are emails that get sent, data is written to and read from databases, etc.).  Perhaps this could all be done without Perl, but that is the way I do this kind of project.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I'd be interested to know why you say I can't use Perl.  You may well be correct, but I have used Perl to use other jquery scripts.  I use print statements to print the HTML, Javascript, etc., and it seems to work just fine.  Perhaps there's something specific to my request, though, that precludes using Perl.  If so, I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the "Perl" tag.  I can see why it would be unnecessary to include it, since Perl is not really part of the equation in terms of the ability to do what I've asked about in my original post.

Comment: Sure, you can generate JavaScript code with Perl. You can also generate C code with Perl, but that doesn't mean Perl is actually doing anything when you run the result. The code that's actually checking the dates and filling in the fields will be JavaScript, Perl has nothing to do with it. (Also, you really shouldn't generate JavaScript with Perl anyway. It couples the code too tightly and makes refactoring difficult.)

Comment: please include your html, including the 3 datepickers, and the placeholder for where you want to display the earliest date. And of course your javascript that you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minimal example - no validation of dates in the date picker fields, etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/sdjwoo0a/

HTML

```
<input name='date1' type='text' class='picky' placeholder='Date 1' />
<input name='date2' type='text' class='picky' placeholder='Date 2' />
<input name='date3' type='text' class='picky' placeholder='Date 3' />
<input id='earliest_date' name='earliest' type='text' readonly placeholder='Earliest' />
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $('input.picky').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
    $(this).change(updateEarliest);
  });

  function updateEarliest() {
    var dates = [];
    $('input.picky').each(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val != '') {
        dates.push({
          val: val,
          date: new Date(val)
        });
      }
    });
    dates.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.date > b.date ? 1 : a.date < b.date ? -1 : 0;
    });
    var earliest = dates.length ? dates.shift().val : '';
    $('#earliest_date').val(earliest);
  }
});
```